# Is it possible to create a table in Athena where two columns bear the name "E" and "e" respectively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am currently creating an external table in Athena from data I have in my S3 Bucket. The only problem is that I have four variables where two are named respectively "E" and "e" and the two others "U" and "u". When I create my table it shows all the columns, but once I query a SELECT statement, it skips the "E" and "U". Is Athena case insensitive? And if yes then why are they shown here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Athena accepts mixed case in DDL and DML queries, but lower cases the names when it executes the query. When creating a table with mixed case, Athena will lowercase the name for you to run the query, but display the column heading using the casing that you chose in the query.

For this reason, avoid using mixed case for table or column names, and do not rely on casing alone in Athena to distinguish such names.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html

Answer (score 0):

If the data is JSON you can possibly use the case insensitivity and mapping features of the OpenX JSON serde to fix it, but I'm not sure if they work on properties of structs.

Look for `case.insensitive` and `mapping` in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json-serde.html – there is a note about how to do this for top-level properties, but whether or not it works for struct properties I don't know.